# Transparency effect with JQuery.SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, transparency, lighting, svg-filters

I've draw a svg path using the great Jquery.SVG (the documentation could be better)

Everything works fine. But I am trying to do something fancier.

There is a colored rectangle and I'd like to highlight it using specularLighting.

I was thinking some code like this:

$('#path-svg-id','#divid').filters.specularLighting(filter, 'specOut', 
    'blur', 5, 0.75, 20, 
    {lightingColor: '#bbbbbb'});

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following and it worked really well

```
svg.ellipse(w, h,  w, h, {stroke: 'red', fill:'transparent'});
```

Comment: `fill: 'none'` is probably better (and compliant to SVG 1.1), 'transparent' will be displayed as black in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [feSpecularLighting](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feSpecularLightingElement) element as a child of a [filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterElement) element, and the [feSpecularLighting](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feSpecularLightingElement) element should have a [light source element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermLightSourceElement) child.

Then you can apply the filter to an element of your choice via the CSS [filter property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterProperty).

See [this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/images/filters/filters01.svg) of feSpecularLighting applied to some svg content.